# dropdown select value conflict with calender in angular js

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

i am workng with two dropdown list and same time we need two calender in it. can anybody tell me why my calender is not showing ??
when i use dropdown list code my calender stops working.
output i need is something like this :- 
(1) 2 days and 5 hours 
(2) 5 days and 4 hours 
(3) 8 days and 13 hours
here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
      <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.2.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="http://tarruda.github.com/bootstrap-datetimepicker/assets/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.2.2/js/bootstrap.min.js">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://tarruda.github.com/bootstrap-datetimepicker/assets/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js">
    </script>
    <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.4.0-beta.3" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.0-beta.3/angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>

        <script data-require="angular.js@1.0.x" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.min.js" data-semver="1.0.8"></script>


    <script src="app.js"></script>


  </head>

  <body><div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl" ng-init="firstTime=endTime=a=selected_id1=selected_id2=input.param1=input.param2=''">
       <div ng-repeat='select in selects'  ng-init="firstTime=endTime=a=selected_id1=selected_id2=select.param1=select.param2=''"> Start Date
    <div id="date" class="input-append" datetimez ng-model="input.var1" >
          <input data-format="MM-dd-yyyy" type="text" id="input1" name="input1" ></input> 
          <span class="add-on">
            <i data-time-icon="icon-time" data-date-icon="icon-calendar"></i>
          </span>
        </div>



        <div id="date" class="input-append" datetimez ng-model="input.var2">
          <input data-format="MM-dd-yyyy" type="text" id="input1" name="input1" ></input> 
          <span class="add-on">
            <i data-time-icon="icon-time" data-date-icon="icon-calendar"></i>
          </span>
        </div>
      <select 
      ng-model="select.selected_id1" 
      ng-options="o.id as o.name for o in options" 
      ng-change="selected_name1=(options|filter:{id:selected_id1})[0].name">
    </select>
    <select 
      ng-model="select.selected_id2" 
      ng-options="o.id as o.name for o in options" 
      ng-change="selected_name2=(options|filter:{id:selected_id2})[0].name">
    </select>



  <button type='button' ng-click='remove(select)'>Remove</button>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button type='button' ng-click='add()'>Add</button>
    <p>Time Difference:{{test()}}</p>


  </div>

  <script>
    angular.module("app",[])
      .controller("ctrl",['$scope',function($scope){


        $scope.options = [
          {id:9, name:'09:00 AM'},
          {id:10, name:'10:00 AM'},
          {id:11, name:'11:00 AM'},
          {id:12, name:'12:00 PM'},
          {id:13, name:'13:00 AM'},    
          {id:14, name:'14:00 AM'},
          {id:15, name:'15:00 AM'},
          {id:16, name:'16:00 AM'},
          {id:17, name:'17:00 PM'},
          {id:18, name:'18:00 AM'}]

          $scope.test = function()
          {
              var result=0,id2,a,b;


             angular.forEach($scope.selects, function(value) { // loop over array to process all items

            a = value.selected_id1;
            b = value.selected_id2;
            //alert(a);
            //alert(b);
            if((a!="") && (b!=""))
            {
                result +=(parseInt(b)-parseInt(a));
                //alert("result is:" + result);


            }
    });
            return result;  
          }
            $scope.selects = [{}]; // default 1 sets
  $scope.add = function() {
    $scope.selects.push({});
  }
   $scope.remove = function(item) {
    angular.forEach($scope.selects, function(value, key) {
      if (value == item) {
        $scope.selects.splice(key, 1);
      }
    });
  }


      }]);
    app.directive('datetimez', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require : 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
          element.datetimepicker({
            dateFormat:'dd-MM-yyyy',
           language: 'en',
           pickTime: false,
           startDate: '01-11-2013',      // set a minimum date
           endDate: '01-11-2030'          // set a maximum date
          }).on('changeDate', function(e) {
            ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(e.date);
            scope.$apply();
          });
        }
    };
});  

  </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Have you thought about using Angular-UI bootstrap: https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

Comment: Slightly off-topic: you are using twice `ng-init="firstTime=endTime=a=selected_id1=selected_id2=input.param1=input.param2=''"` Be careful with ng-init, read about it here https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit

Comment: PS: It is better to use Plunker than copy-pasting code here ...

Comment: angular bootstrap is not providing such facilities,so that we can easily customize the calender behavior

Comment: @david let me create an account in plunker.. wait

Comment: am back again..... and here is my plunker code sir http://plnkr.co/edit/20PLT52Ia86UyGClQh7h?p=preview

Comment: now can you please help ?

Comment: @Nitish your app.js in plunkr is empty. And expression inside `ng-init` is not valid. Open browser console, you will see there error message `Error: Syntax Error: Token '=' is an unexpected token at column 18 of the expression [firstTime=endTime=a=selected_id1=selected_id2=input.param1=input.param2=''] starting at [=a=selected_id1=selected_id2=input.param1=input.param2=''].`

Comment: actually our code dont need this app.js anymore... it was for testing only

Answer (score 0):

Your expression inside `ng-init` is not valid.
Try something like this `ng-init="a=b;c=d"` etc... - Separate commands with `;`

Another question is where those values inside ng-init come from? Do you REALLY need ng-init there?

**UPDATE**

if values of a,b,c... are supposed to be null, then there is no need to initialize them

Comment: am using ng-init="a = b= c= ' ' ";  to initialize a,b,c,d as empty ng-model. in next step in future i will use these model to hold and store data for temporary basis

Comment: output i need is something like this :- 
(1) 2 days and 5 hours 
(2) 5 days and 4 hours 
(3) 8 days and 13 hours
result =  (1)+(2)+(3); 
13 days and 24 hours

Comment: yes i know, i'll use them in future...this code will have some more logics ahead